# Doctrine: how to return the row count of a records in a groupby statement

Tags: doctrine

Seems like such a simple thing, but I can't get my query to return the number of records in a group.  Here's my statement:

```
public function getGroupCount($user_id)
{
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('ss.*')
        ->from('SalarySurvey ss')
        ->where('ss.user_id=?', $user_id)
        ->groupBy('created_at')
        ->execute();
    return $q->rowCount();
}
```

rowCount() does not work in the above query.

It might also be helpful to know that this is being used in a foreach statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CappY suggested, this is not possible in Doctrine 1.2, as far as I know.  As a work-around,  I was able to finally get a count for each grouping by adding another field to the table and setting that field the same for each group at save time.  Then I changed my query to pull that field and just did a simple:

```
$q->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never work with Doctrine 1.2, but can't U use php's [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function or SELECT COUNT() AS 'cnt' ?

return count($q);

Comment: I tried something similar to your suggestion without success.  However, I was able to fix my issue which I will post in an answer.  But you are correct... at least it has been my experience so far... that doctrine does not allow this.  So, please leave your answer for those who stumble upon this question looking for answers.